# How download images from ftp

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting, files

I imported products with the help of feeds via commerce product processor. The images from http://example.com/image.jpg downloaded successfully.  But why does not loading the images from ftp://account:123@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/image.jpg ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the image actually does not below at `/image.jpg`. You need to investigate where you are storing your files at `admin/config/media/file-system`. And from there you might find where is your files locate.

The default file path is going to be `/sites/default/files` so it might be ftp://account:123@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sites/default/filesimage.jpg.

Comment: Nonono. I imported products from csv file. Product's image loaded correctly from http://..... or https://.... etc. But if i change link to image in csv file to ftp://... image not dowloaded - all product's data loaded correctly except the product photo

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you also have to check your image field path settings under `/admin/structure/types/manage/[contentelement]/fields`.